# Realizing a *-algebra as an endomorphism algebra

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

A $*$-ring is a (unitial, associative, not necessarily commutative) ring $A$ with a map $* : A \rightarrow A$ (we write $*(a) = a^*$), such that

1. $1^* = 1$.
2. $\forall a, b \in A, (a + b)^* = a^* + b^*$.
3. $\forall a, b \in A , (ab)^* = b^* a^*$.
4. $\forall a \in A , a^{**} = a$.

An example is $\text{End}(V)$ for a dualizable object $V$ of a monoidal closed $\text{Ab}$-enriched category $C$. Multiplication is composition of linear maps, and the star operation is adjoint.

My question is:

> Let $A$ be a $*$-algebra. Is there an $\text{Ab}$-enriched monoidal closed category $C$ and an object $V$ with a nondegenerate bilinear form in $C$ such that $A$ is isomorphic to the star ring $\text{End}_C(V)$?

$\text{End}_C(V)$ gets its adjoint map via the identification $V \cong V^*$ (this comes from the nondegenerate bilinear form).

Comment: What is your definition of the “adjoint”?  The usual definition of the adjoint map of f:X→Y produces f*:Y*→X*, where X* and Y* are duals of X and Y.  In particular, the dual of f:X→X is a map of the form f*:X*→X*.  X and X* need not be isomorphic, so f* does not yield a map X→X.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Sorry, I intended to endow $V$ with a nondegenrate bilinear form. I will fix it for us.

Comment: In this case, can't you simply take the one-object delooping of A?  That is, the Ab-enriched closed monoidal category with a single object whose endomorphisms are A?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov you're right - I didn't realize it was so easy. For some reason I thought that wouldn't be closed under tensor, but it definitely is.